# how to handle back press in fragments and activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, tabs, onbackpressed

[image]I have tab fragment which contains 3 fragments : fragment A fragment B fragment c.
1) Now on click of item from fragment A activity opens. How to handle back pressed and back button in this case.

2) Now on click of item from fragment C activity opens which contains 3 tabs containing fragment X fragment y fragment z . how to handle back press and back button in this case.

Can anybody help me out ???

Comment: In Fragment 

getActivity().onBackPressed();

Answer (score 0):

Use this code for default back button:

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
            super.onBackPressed();
            this.finish();
    }
```

for back image button simply use `finish()` in `onClickListener();`

```
Button backButton = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.back);
backButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {
    finish();
  }
});
```

if previous Activity already closed then use **Intent** to navigate:

```
 Button backButton = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.back);
    backButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {

       Intent i = new Intent(currentActivity.this, previousActivity.class);     
       startActivity(i);
       finish(); 

      }
    });
```

Comment: i tried second solution with image button but it directly closes the application :(

Comment: where did you applied this??

Comment: i have a fragment which contains recycleview on click of item activity opens so now on back press i want to go from curent activity back to fragment how can i do it??

Comment: i have used intent but its not smoothly back pressing

Comment: check may be other views taking time to load but if you want to move from one activity to another you must use intent

Answer (score 0):

first make method on activity where the fragment is loaded. for example i load the fragment on activity **NavigationDrawer.class**

```
public Fragment getVisibleFragment(){
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = NavigationDrawer.this.getSupportFragmentManager();
    List<Fragment> fragments = fragmentManager.getFragments();
    if(fragments != null){
        for(Fragment fragment : fragments){
            if(fragment != null && fragment.isVisible())
                return fragment;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

then, call the method

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

       //call the method
    if (getVisibleFragment()!=null) {

        //check which current visible fragment
        String nameFragment = getVisibleFragment().toString();
        if (nameFragment.contains("nameFragmentA")) {
            //your action A
         }else if(nameFragment.contains("nameFragmentB")){
            //your action B
         }else{
           //another action
         }

       }
}
```

It can apply to questions 1 and 2. Hope this help you!